# Incomplete syntax highlighting in vim

Tags: python, vim, syntax-highlighting

Using Python as an example, vim will highlight `list`, but not `collections.defaultdict(list)`
and `len`, but not `len()`. Anyone have any idea what the reason for this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please post the contents of your `/usr/share/vim/vim72/syntax/python.vim` file?
My vim doesn't hilight builtin functions, unless I uncomment the string

```
"        let python_highlight_builtins = 1
```

When I do so, both `len` and `len()` get hilighted properly.

Answer (score 0):

How would you like `collections.defaultdict(list)` to be highlighted? Vim's default Python syntax file doesn't seem to define a syntax group for function calls, only function definitions (`pythonFunction`). `collections` and `defaultdict` are not recognized either. `list` is highlighted because it's recognized as a builtin  (`pythonBuiltin`).

How would you like `len()` to be highlighted? `len` is highlighted because it is recognized as a builtin (`pythonBuiltin`) but `len()` is not a builtin: it's a builtin followed by parenthesis. Would you like the parenthesis to be highlighted as well? With the same color? Another color?

You could try to customize `/usr/share/vim/vim7x/syntax/python.vim` to your needs or [look for a "better" syntax file](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script_search_results.php?keywords=python&script_type=syntax&order_by=creation_date&direction=descending&search=search).